# How to effectively create list using if in java8?

Tags: java-8

I have started learning Java8.I have been following traditional way to create a list(for the below code) using `if` condition.My code is working but is there any effective way to achieve this using java8? Please let me know

```
private List<String> getDeliveryAddressTypeList() {
    List<String> deliveryAddressTypeList = new ArrayList<>();
    deliveryAddressTypeList.add(DeliveryAddressType.MY_DEFAULT_ADDRESS.getValue());
    if (SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted(PermissionConstant.PHARMISA_DELIVERY_PFDEPORTS)) {
        deliveryAddressTypeList.add(DeliveryAddressType.DEPOT_ADDRESS.getValue());
    }
    if (SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted(PermissionConstant.PHARMISA_DELIVERY_ALL_CONTACTS)) {
        deliveryAddressTypeList.add(DeliveryAddressType.CONTACT_ADDRESS.getValue());
    }
    if (SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted(PermissionConstant.PHARMISA_DELIVERY_FREE_FROM_ADDRESS)) {
        deliveryAddressTypeList.add(DeliveryAddressType.AN_ALTERNATIVE_ADDRESS.getValue());
    }
    return deliveryAddressTypeList;
}
```

Comment: In above code `if`condition's return true or false.if true i have added to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the cleanest way is as you have it. Nonetheless, you could use a helper method to avoid repeated `if` statements:

```
static void addIfPermitted(List<String> list, DeliveryAddressType addressType, 
    PermissionConstant permission) {

    if (SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted(permission) {
        list.add(addressType.getValue());
    }
}
```

Now you can use this helper method this way:

```
List<String> deliveryAddressTypeList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
    DeliveryAddressType.MY_DEFAULT_ADDRESS.getValue()));

addIfPermitted(deliveryAddressTypeList, 
    DeliveryAddressType.DEPOT_ADDRESS, 
    PermissionConstant.PHARMISA_DELIVERY_PFDEPORTS);

addIfPermitted(deliveryAddressTypeList, 
    DeliveryAddressType.CONTACT_ADDRESS, 
    PermissionConstant.PHARMISA_DELIVERY_ALL_CONTACTS);

addIfPermitted(deliveryAddressTypeList, 
    DeliveryAddressType.AN_ALTERNATIVE_ADDRESS, 
    PermissionConstant.PHARMISA_DELIVERY_FREE_FROM_ADDRESS);
```

If you want to use java 8 stuff, you could create a `Map<DeliveryAddressType, PermissionConstant>`:

```
List<String> deliveryAddressTypeList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
    DeliveryAddressType.MY_DEFAULT_ADDRESS.getValue()));

Map<DeliveryAddressType, PermissionConstant> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put(DeliveryAddressType.DEPOT_ADDRESS, 
    PermissionConstant.PHARMISA_DELIVERY_PFDEPORTS);
map.put(DeliveryAddressType.CONTACT_ADDRESS, 
    PermissionConstant.PHARMISA_DELIVERY_ALL_CONTACTS);
map.put(DeliveryAddressType.AN_ALTERNATIVE_ADDRESS, 
    PermissionConstant.PHARMISA_DELIVERY_FREE_FROM_ADDRESS);
```

And then:

```
map.forEach((addressType, permission) -> 
    addIfPermitted(deliveryAddressList, adressType, permission));
```

Another way, using streams and the same map, but creating the final list from the map keys:

```
List<String> deliveryAddressTypeList = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted(e.getValue()))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .map(DeliveryAddressType::getValue)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

deliveryAddressTypeList.add(DeliveryAddressType.MY_DEFAULT_ADDRESS.getValue());
```

Here you filter map entries and keep only the ones whose value (`PermissionConsdtant`) is permitted by the security. Then you transform each filtered entry into its key (`DeliveryAddressType`) and then transform each `DeliveryAddressType` into its value. Finally, you collect all these delivery address type values to a list.

Answer (score 4):

You may separate the code and the data. Initialize the static map like this:

```
Map<DeliveryAddressType, Predicate<Subject>> permissions = new HashMap<>();
permissions.put(DeliveryAddressType.MY_DEFAULT_ADDRESS, s -> true);
permissions.put(DeliveryAddressType.DEPOT_ADDRESS, 
    s -> s.isPermitted(PermissionConstant.PHARMISA_DELIVERY_PFDEPORTS));
permissions.put(DeliveryAddressType.CONTACT_ADDRESS, 
    s -> s.isPermitted(PermissionConstant.PHARMISA_DELIVERY_ALL_CONTACTS));
permissions.put(DeliveryAddressType.AN_ALTERNATIVE_ADDRESS, 
    s -> s.isPermitted(PermissionConstant.PHARMISA_DELIVERY_FREE_FROM_ADDRESS));
```

Now you can use

```
private List<String> getDeliveryAddressTypeList() {
    Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
    return permissions.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().test(subject))
        .map(entry -> entry.getKey().getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the mapping `PermissionConstant -> DeliveryAddressType`.
Assuming you have defined a constant `Map<PermissionConstant, DeliveryAddressType>` like (if insertion order matters you can also use a `LinkedHashMap`)

```
Map<PermissionConstant, DeliveryAddressType> mappings = new HashMap<>();
mappings.put(PermissionConstant.PHARMISA_DELIVERY_PFDEPORTS, DeliveryAddressType.DEPOT_ADDRESS);
mappings.put(PermissionConstant.PHARMISA_DELIVERY_ALL_CONTACTS, DeliveryAddressType.CONTACT_ADDRESS);
mappings.put(PermissionConstant.PHARMISA_DELIVERY_FREE_FROM_ADDRESS, DeliveryAddressType.AN_ALTERNATIVE_ADDRESS);
```

Then you cans simply concat and stream the map to get the result:

```
private static List<String> getDeliveryAddressTypeList() {
  Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
  return Stream.concat(
      Stream.of(DeliveryAddressType.MY_DEFAULT_ADDRESS.getValue()),
        mappings.entrySet().stream()
          .filter(m -> subject.isPermitted(m.getKey()))
          .map(m -> m.getValue().getValue())
      ).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```